# How do I save a self-made dataset in Python so that I can use it later?

Tags: python, dataset

I created a dataset of arrays from PNG images. How can I save this dataset in Python such that I can access it later or in another Python script without having to rescan all the images?

Comment: For small datasets `pickle` should be OK, as pointed out below in Brobin's answer.  If you want more fancy stuff like key-based or relational databases, you'll need something like `bsddb` or `sqlite`, both with Python bindings.  If you need high-performance, cross-platform floating-point access for huge datasets, `pytables` looks like a natural choice.

Comment: my dataset is about 30,000 PNGs so could I still use pickle or would I need something more substantial?

Comment: it all depends on what you get from those 30,000 image files.  If that's not too large just sticking with `pickle` is OK.  Maybe some examples?

Comment: I am just saving the numpy array representation of the image. i.e the RGB values stored in the array

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that might be too much data to store in a pickle.

Answer (score 7):

You can use python's [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) library to dump the data to a file.

```
import pickle

dataset = [1,2,3,4]

with open('my_dataset.pickle', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(dataset, output)
```

then you can load it back in another script.

```
import pickle

with open('my_dataset.pickle', 'rb') as data:
    dataset = pickle.load(data)
```